# convert base64 string to image with image magick in perl

Tags: perl, api

I am trying to send an image to my server which is base64 encoded (minus the starting bit about data:image/jpeg;base64, ).

I want to upload the image after making a thumbnail of it - I am using image magick.

How do I get image magick to read my base64 string as an image, so that I can modify and save it?

my code so far:

```
my $extension = 'jpg';
my $full_filename = $photo_filepath . $cand->id . '.' . $extension;

require Image::Magick;
my $cand_photo = Image::Magick->new;
my $decoded = decode_base64($args{image_string});
$cand_photo->read(blob=>$decoded);

#save original
$cand_photo->Write($full_filename);

#resize
$cand_photo->Set( Gravity => 'Center' );
$cand_photo->Resize( geometry => '120x120' );
$cand_photo->Extent( geometry => '120x120' );
my $full_filename_120
    = $photo_filepath . $cand->id . '_120x120.' . $extension;

#save thumbnail
$cand_photo->Write($full_filename_120);
```

**EDIT**: have got this working, code above is actually correct, the problem was elsewhere for me !

Answer (score 2):

Not sure how it's done in `Image::Magick`, may I suggest `MIME::Base64`, it's a core module.

```
my $image_decoded= MIME::Base64::decode_base64($image_string);
open (my $handle, '>', 'image_file.jpg') or die $!;
binmode $handle;
print $handle $image_decoded;
close ($handle);
```