# How to load image from form directly into ImageMagick with Perl

Tags: forms, perl, upload, imagemagick

Currently I am using the following code to allow a user to upload an image via a html form. It creates a copy of the image which I then read in to ImageMagick. But of course it would be way better to simply read the data from the form straight into the ImageMagick object. But I have not been able to achieve that.

```
use Image::Magick;
use MIME::Base64;
$arg = new CGI;
$fetch_photo = param('fileuploadphoto');
($data, $base64) = split /,/, $fetch_photo;
($type) = $data =~ m!data:image/(\w+);base64!;
$decoded = MIME::Base64::decode_base64($base64);
$filename = 'test.jpg';
open(my $file, '>', "$filename") or die "Error cannot open file: $file"; 
binmode $file;
print $file $decoded;
close($file);
$image = Image::Magick->new;
$image->Read($filename);
```

Comment: You should be able to to use the `Read()` method with a blob, `$image->Read(blob => $decoded)`, see also [convert base64 string to image with image magick in perl](https://stackoverflow.com/q/27817744/2173773)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to Håkon Hægland for the answer. This works perfectly.

```
use Image::Magick;
use MIME::Base64;
$fetch_photo = param('fileuploadphoto');
($data, $base64) = split /,/, $fetch_photo;
$decoded = MIME::Base64::decode_base64($base64);
$image = Image::Magick->new;
$image->Read(blob => $decoded);
```